# e.target.is("#elelemt - or any child of it")

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

We are using multipe modal on one of our site, now i want to close the actual open modal, when you are clicking outside of the div of the modal. How can i use the parent modal or any child element in a .is()

The PHP part is only to handle the different modals and buttons.

````
jq(document).on("click touchstart", function(e) {
  if (jq(e.target).is("#modal<?php echo $this->id ?>")) {
    return
  }
  else {
        modal<?php echo $this->id; ?>.style.display = "none";
        btn<?php echo $this->id; ?>.style.display = "block";
  }
})```
````

Comment: I don't understand why you need to capture the clicks in the modal. Just capture any click outside the modal and close it. No?

Comment: The Problem is, when you click "outside" of the opend modal, you should be able to click on the other button to open the next one.  I think this is the problem why i just can't close if you click outside.